# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found using pandas even though the url exists

Tags: python, pandas, csv, url, https

I was trying to run this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\Finsearch\AAPL.csv")
df = df.sort_values(by="Date")
df = df.dropna()
# calculate returns
df = df.assign(close_day_before=df.Close.shift(1))
df['returns'] = ((df.Close - df.close_day_before)/df.close_day_before)

# get options data from yahoo finance // in this case, exercise data is july 24th
r = pd.read_html('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?date=1655424000&p=AAPL')[0]
```

It shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\Finsearch\finserach.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = pd.read_html('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?date=1655424000&p=AAPL')[0]
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1098, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 906, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 222, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 745, in _build_doc
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 726, in _build_doc
    with urlopen(self.io) as f:
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 211, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found``
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you posted seems to indicate that the error is coming from code that you have not posted in your question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "c:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\Finsearch\finserach.py", 
line 10, in **r = pd.read_html('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?date=1655424000&p=AAPL')**[0] File
```

Specifically, the **r = pd_read_html('...)** portion.

Comment: Yes that is the line showing error, i guess i missed that line while formatting the code, my bad.